# In TFS (2015), how to trigger build based on a file updated?

Tags: tfs

In TFS, continuous build can be triggered when changes to the repository are detected. I am looking for a feature to trigger only the build when a specific file changes.

I have a library that I want to publish to an internal nuget server. I versioned the library manually in the nuspec file. I want to trigger build and publish when the  nuspec file gets updated. Is this doable in TFS?

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git? The options are slightly different between the two.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **TFVC**, you can specify the file directly in CI filter.

For Git in TFS 2015 , there is no such feature or setting to specific a folder within the repo by default ([it's available in VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/news/2016#june-14)), as Repository and CI filter are used for different purpose:

> Repository specifies which files will be downloaded from your remote
>   repository into a local sources directory by build agent at the
>   beginning of the build process.
>
> CI filter selects the version control paths you want to include and
>   exclude.

There is a [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/16267636-build-2015-vnext-triggers-continous-integration) submitted for using repository paths as default, which similar as TFVC. Microsoft Product Team will evaluate it carefully. You can go there and vote it up to achieve it in future.

[image]

Comment: @alltej Have you resolved the issue? any update for this?